# Is it possible to configure query timeout in Azure SQL Database?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have an Azure SQL Database and I can't find where to configure Query Timeout for all queries running on that database. Right now I have queries that run for days and even though I think all applications should have connection timeouts set, I also believe that there should be a way for the database itself to timeout the connection.

Is it possible to do this configuration for Azure SQL Database?

Comment: You could use [`CommandTimeout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout?view=netframework-4.8) to enforce a client-side timeout.

Answer (score -2):

In SSMS, **Tool**--> **Options**-->**Query Execution**, we can set the Execution time-out:

[image]

I connect to me Azrue sql database with SSMS. I'm not sure if this works for Azure SQL database. We can't find the query time-out time of Azure SQL database, I once ran a query that took me more than 10 minutes.  We can not find anything talked about it in Azure SQL document.

Hope this helps.